# Teams in browers opens up new tab when Launch() function is used from within Power App (canvas)

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm doing a custom Power App (canvas) that is used inside Teams as a Tab in a channel. This app has some deeplinks to other channels inside teams (the link url is copied from within teams and are verified and works ok). I'm using the Launch() function to do these deeplink redirects. I get the desired behavior in the Desktop and Mobile version of Teams, but in the browser version whatever I try it always open up the link in a new tab. I would like it to open up in the same window and keep the navigation context for a smooth UX.

I've tried booth LaunchTarget.New and LaunchTarget.Replace. Also used booth 'https://' and 'msteams://' in the deeplink urls. I would expect that the LaunchTarget.Replace would have done what I wanted, but it doesn't work.

The only way I've seen links working as expected in all three versions of teams (Desktop, Mobile and Browser). Is if I manually insert a link inside a message in a 'Posts' tab or if I manually insert a link inside a Wiki. If I do the same in for example a OneNote document it doesn't work and open up in a new Tab. Its quite inconsistent behavior.

Any help, info or workaround is appropriated.

Comment: We are seeing the same behavior; we are discussing internally. We will get back to you.

Comment: Deep links from a Platform App to other parts of Teams need to go through our [executeDeepLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/?view=msteams-client-js-latest#@microsoft-teams-js-executedeeplink) SDK API.

Comment: If using the V2 SDK, the API has been renamed to [app.openLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/app?view=msteams-client-js-latest#@microsoft-teams-js-app-openlink). Teams cannot automatically intercept these links across all clients (e.g. in browsers, hosted apps run in a cross-origin iframe that we have very limited control over); therefore, we rely on apps passing them to us via the SDK. And Launch() is generic for all clients, and it just asks the host to navigate.